# Как вытащить строку из скобок в Python?

Tags: python

У меня возникла проблема, как достать`('bfd3b5241726a',)` вот это в Python 3.6? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не скобки, а [кортеж](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) - разновидность коллекции.

```
t = ('bfd3b5241726a',)
v = t[0]
```

Comment: Спасибо вы очень помогли!!!